# Change font color in ul li using class

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic menu that is generated by a CMS in the following format:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">Dashboard</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
.nav a {
    color: #777;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color: green;
}
.btn-blue {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.btn-blue:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The problem here is that the class "btn-blue" isn't respected. The color code for btn-blue doesn't seem to work. How do I resolve this problem?

Here's the **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vok80qkf/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all boils down to specificity. Try this instead, for your css:

```
.nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

.nav a {
    color: #777;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: green;
}

.nav .btn-blue {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.nav .btn-blue:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

If you want to read more about this, here is a post on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Thank You. I was scratching my head all over for over 2 hours now!! Was finally deciding to use `!important` but thought i'll post here first :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `.nav a` is a more specific selector that `.btn-blue`. Take a look at the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for a lot more information on specificity

As for your problem, just change `.btn-blue` to `.nav .btn-blue`.